# Using "nice" command with an alias

Tags: bash

How can I use the "nice" command with an alias?

As an example:

```
alias list=ls
list # works
nice -10 list # doesn't work
```

How could I make that last line work?

Comment: Hey, you shouldn't have deleted that... I enjoyed the explanation of the only good use for alias! :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by OBFUSCATING in this context. The actual alias is a bit more complicated, defined in a profile file. Not something I want to start repeating across different scripts.

Comment: Obfuscate: Render obscure, unclear, to mask, hide, cover up, or make unintelligible. Source: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+obfuscate&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Comment: Thanks, familiar with the dictionary definition, but still not sure what it means _in this context_.

Comment: It means you are covering up what the command list actually is. Its not really a problem because this is a private script but if you choose to distribute, it could get ugly. In general code obfuscation is a bad practice.

Comment: It's easier to explain clearly and encourage people to answer with a simple example, and in this case I've been able to successfully use @eljunior's answer, so the example was fine.

Comment: Good luck with your project. I hope everything works out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alias is a shell feature, and `nice` is an external program:

```
$ type nice
nice is hashed (/usr/bin/nice)
```

It's the program `nice` that runs the command passed as an argument, calling the C function `execve`, so all the arguments for it need to be evaluated BEFORE the call.

So, it would probably better not to use an alias and simply put the whole command needed there, but if you really want to, you could try something like this:

```
$ nice -10 `alias list | sed "s/^\(alias \)\?[^=]\+='//; s/'$//;"`
```

`alias list` prints the alias definition in the format `alias list='ls'` (or `list='ls'`, if it's `/bin/sh`), so I did some sed substitutions there to get only the command it expands to.

If you're sure to use only `bash` you can use `${BASH_ALIASES[list]}` instead, as pointed out in the comments:

```
$ nice -10 ${BASH_ALIASES[list]}
```

Comment: `${BASH_ALIASES[list]}` might be easier than using `sed`

Comment: I still don't see how this is any different than creating a variable for export either.

The end result is the expansion of a variable here. I already covered that. And it would be safer to have private var such as MYLISTCMD__XXX But oh well. You get what you pay for.

Answer (score 1):

Though perhaps not as exotically exciting as `nice -10 $UserVar1;` or `nice -10 ${BASH_ALIASES[list]}`, you may also have the `nice -10 list` you asked for, though via wrapper script instead of alias:

```
# one-time setup
mkdir -p ~/.local/aliases
echo 'PATH=$HOME/.local/aliases:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
# open new terminal window, or
source ~/.bashrc

# create the wrapper. $@ to passthrough args.
echo 'ls $@' > ~/.local/aliases/list
chmod +x ~/.local/aliases/list

nice -10 list # works :)
nice -10 list --color=always -lathr # args passthrough also works :)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Zsh BASH_ALIASES will not work. So you may use it like this:

```
nice -10 `list`
```

Comment: This seems to evaluate `list` first without `nice`, and the send the resulting output of `list` to `nice` as a command

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea. You are defining a command alias but are not even using it as an alias expansion. Poor coding practice here. This is what you want.

```
declare -x UserVar1='ls';

nice -10 $UserVar1;
```

And if you will not change the definition of UserVar1 later on in your code. There are zero reasons you can justify to use a variable instead of the actual command name.

You are headed for disaster. **Plain and simple**. Use a variable or the command name itself it is far safer and marginally more efficient and easier to read.